# To set up Apache Web-Server with apt-cacher on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, apt-cacher

Did anybody try the goal described below. We are going to do so and want probe here how the chances for success are.

The goal is to have apt-cacher in following environment.

-) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop or later Ubuntu LTS Desktop

..means Apache Web-Server needs to be installed and configured too

-) mentioned Ubuntu is a virtual machine powered by VirtualBox

.. it uses NAT Network Adapter towards physical host.

-) apt-cacher clients are also virtual machines on the same physical host (VirtualBox and other sw virtualization solutions).

..One apt-cacher client runs on the same virtual machine as the cacher

-) later, some clients on other physical hosts but the same local network

Comment: So far following goal was achieved: apt client on same virtual machine as the apt-cacher. Apt-cacher is started manually, no demand to let it run always and autostart with host OS. Next goal to be achieved: get apt clients running on other VMs on same physical host working with the apt-cacher. Results follow as any available.

Answer (score 0):

I got into a mess using apt-cacher. Also, it only caches for one version. Rather setup trafficserver.apache.org and configure to be a general cache proxy for network traffic. You can set a rule for *.deb.

Comment: Actually, one can see in the cacher manual that the stand-alone is supported. It simplifies the task significantly. Any-though you point out an highly interesting point, that with caching for one version only.  trafficserver.apache.org seems to be something external to our local network and to cover whole traffic external to it. It is not our aim.

Comment: You want to save bandwidth, but consider that Debian package manager is one of many. Ruby Gems? Python Eggs? Are you developers? Sure, a proxy introduces possible network bottleneck, and users might not like the idea of a MITM node. Are you caching for servers, PCs, or notebooks? If there are notebooks then when trying to update from another network that could be problematic, I don't remember too well. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable hints. We are pretty sure that connected clients are using package manager of no other type than Debian's one. We are not caching for servers. Clients are workstations, desktops. There are not multiple networks, only one LAN is addressed. I am sorry I did not got all your intentions. External proxies seem to be oversized for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `apt-cacher-ng` since 2012 on a virtual machine to provide updates for about 10 other virtual machines running different versions of ubuntu.

Setting it up is pretty easy, the server offers a web-interface which gives some informations, but i never use it.

In the client-side i have to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` and add there

```
Acquire::http { Proxy "http://CACHER-IP:3142"; };
```

If you havent so far- take some time and start working on it. Its really a nice solution and if you have it running once its a self-runner.

Feel free to ask further if i missed something.

Comment: Thanks for feedback from you and sorry for long delay. It is good for me to know your experiences. Finally I switched to acng too but still in troubles. Is it possible for you to take a look in my new question http://askubuntu.com/q/788705/385230. It describes my situation. Maybe by comparing with your setup I will be able to find the deciding point. Thanks.